# Customizing the dropdownlist in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, html-select

I am developing a MVC application with a dropdown control .

I have an action in the controller which returns a custom model , which in turns contains 2 lists . 
For example:

**EDIT**

```
public ActionResult Dropdown()
{
    List<DarwinDimitrov.Models.Years> ListYear = new List<DarwinDimitrov.Models.Years>();
    List<DarwinDimitrov.Models.Months> ListMonth = new List<DarwinDimitrov.Models.Months>();
    DarwinDimitrov.Models.Years year = new Years();
    DarwinDimitrov.Models.Months months = new Months();
    year.year = " 2014";
    months.month = "January";
    ListYear.Add(year);
    ListMonth.Add(months);
    var listofMonths = new DropDownData
    {
        month = ListMonth,
        year = ListYear
    };

    return View(listofMonths);
}
```

Model is :

```
public class DropDownData
{
    public IEnumerable<Years> year { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Months> month { get; set; }
}
```

In my view , I collect the list as:

```
@model DarwinDimitrov.Models.DropDownData dropdowndata;
```

So, now my requirement is have to populate two dropdowns, one is with "month" and the second is with "year".

My question is, when I try using:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Dropdown1",
```

I get the options only as

`Model.FirstOrDefault().month` or `Model.First().Month`

Is this the best practice for binding the list or am I missing something here while passing the list from the Controller?

Comment: It sounds like the model itself for that view is an enumeration of `DropDownData` instances, not one instance.

Comment: I replicated your code and I do can say `@Model.month.First().month`. You have to be sure that what is getting to that view is a instances and not something else.